# Identifying a dense subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert space with subspace $A$ such that the orthogonal complement $A^\perp$ of $A$ is trivial, i.e. $A^\perp = \{ 0 \}$, must $A$ be dense in $H$?

Comment: Yes, otherwise there is some element $x$ that cannot be approximated from $A$, and by virtue, neither can the entire subspace generated by $x$ which contradicts the orthogonal complement being trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a simple proof that this is true, use the fact that for a subspace $W$ we have $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} = \overline{W}$; thus the closure of $A$ is the whole space $H$.